# how to show image from php to another

Tags: php, html, sql

I want to show all images from database in interface the page index.php

```html
<?php  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { ?>
<table border="1" width="702" height="149" align="center">
  <tr>
    <td width="148"><img src='get.php' width='200' height='211' /> </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<?php } ?>
```

the code in get.php

```
<?php
include ("config.php");
$image = mysql_query ("SELECT image.image FROM  image JOIN products 
   WHERE  image.id = products.Image_ID");
$image = mysql_fetch_assoc ($image);
$image = $image ['image'];
header ("Content-type: image/jpeg");
echo $image; 
?>
```

but it gives me one image repeated in index.php..
How can I make the code take the Image_ID from the index.php to show all images in the same page?

Comment: You mean `<img src='get.php?ID=<?= $row["ID"] ?>' width='200' height='211' />` ?

Comment: You will need to pass and clean the ID on the  get.php

Comment: You're mixed APIs. You can't do that.

Comment: i used it before but it still show one image..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is your index.php

```
<?php  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { ?>
<table border="1" width="702" height="149" align="center">
    <tr>
        <td width="148"><img src='get.php?id='<?= $row['id'];?> width='200' height='211' /> </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<?php } ?
```

And get.php

```
<?php
include ("config.php");
$image = mysql_query ("SELECT image.image FROM  image JOIN products
WHERE  image.id = '".$_GET['id']."'");
$image = mysql_fetch_assoc ($image);
$image = $image ['image'];
header ("Content-type: image/jpeg");
echo $image;
?>
```

Comment: now it can catch the id ,but it do not show the images..It gives a broken miniature image..

Comment: What you get in $image['image'] ?

Comment: it is convert from text to image,the code - header ("Content-type: image/jpeg"); - does not work.

Comment: check console..Do you get any errors of not found there? Do you upload image in database or in project folder?

Comment: it give me black page

Comment: black page where?

Comment: it give me an image when i put a value of id image in ( SELECT) instead of $_GET['Image_ID']

Comment: black page in get.php

Comment: You have to pass <img src='get.php?Image_ID='<?= $row['id'];?> to get  $_GET['Image_ID']